# How to query on a field that needs to be encrypted?

Tags: encryption

I'm designing an API that uses application level encryption to protect sensitive information in a database.

A simple example of the problem is a user table with the following fields:

- UserID
- Name
- Address
- Telephone Number
- ClientIdentifier

In the above table all fields are sensitive and should be encrypted apart from UserID which is just the primary key of the table. While the primary key exists for foreign key constraints the actual identifying value for the record is ClientIdentifier. This is an ID for the user controlled by the consumer of the API.

When a consumer of the API wishes to create a user record they pass all the details (including the ClientIdentifier) to us which we store. When they want to retrieve those details they again pass us the ClientIdentifier. For this use case, they cannot use the UserID.

It's likely that the ClientIdentifier could be public knowledge e.g. an email address or account number and can be traced back to a real person. Therefore we have to secure ClientIdentifier as the existence of a record would imply that the person exists on our system.

I see a couple of options.

1. Hash the ClientIdentifier. The downside to this is that the ClientIdentifier is likely to follow a fixed format and be vulnerable to brute force attacks.
2. Encrypt all the data but in the case of ClientIdentifier use a fixed IV. The downside here is that an attacker who had access to both the API and the database could execute plain text attacks on the system.

I'm leaning towards to the second option as the plain text attack can probably be mitigated with monitoring of the encryption service, whereas the hashing option could be broken reasonably quickly if a snapshot of the database was lost.

So my question is, do you think I'm on the right track or are there any better alternatives?

Edit: It's possible that we could have multiple records in the database with the same ClientIdentifier. Given a plaintext ID we should be able to select all those records.

Comment: Is it fair to rephrase your problem as "you need to store clientId in the database encrypted. Clients make requests using their ID, and you need to retrieve their row from the database using that clientID (which they've passed to you un-encrypted) without retrieving and descrypting every row on every request" ?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a fair summary

Comment: So, you have to be able to encrypt/decrypt each field. Presumably clientId is no more or less sensitive than address/phone number. So I'd think you'd just encrypt the value you were you given (using whatever your algorithm is) and then search against that encrypted value. See next comment...

Comment: Presumably, though, you'd need a way to verify the client in addition to ID. They're probably passing that via SSL (or certainly should be if its considered secure). In that case you're really treating it like a password. If that's the case, you should treat client ID and password separately, where client ID is encrypted "normally" (assuming that's, say, an e-mail), while the password is stored only as the hash result from the password, so there's no way to reverse that one.

Comment: Agreed the ClientIdentifier is no less sensitive than any other data. The authentication and authorisation is already completed by this stage. The ClientIdentifier is the id of a user, so a particular consumer could have many users within the system each with a different ClientIdentifier

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should use option 2 and use a fixed IV?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting that you probably don't need to treat it any differently than any of the other fields, since they are all already encrypted (particularly since auth is done already). Understand the case is stolen database and API, but if an attacker has done that, they already have access to all of the other fields, correct? So unless clientId is an authenticator (which you've just said it's not), there's no reason to treat it special as compared to name/address/phone (which will equally serve as an identifier of a user).

Comment: Ah except I need to basically do a SELECT * FROM User WHERE ClientIdentifier = [SomeValue]. If I encrypt the ClientIdentifier using the same method as the other fields then I won't be able to run that select because I'll be using a random IV. So even though the database may hold a value of 1234 and the consumer passes in 1234 the encrypted values won't match.

Comment: You still need to know the IV used for encryption to successfully decrypt any of the fields... so again, it's not really different from any other field. Where do you store the IV for the other fields / how is that provided?

Comment: Sorry, in my attempt to simplify the problem I missed off an important criteria. I've updated the question.

Comment: Using field-level encryption is a very bad idea, security-wise.  Very easy to crack, unless very carefully done.  Far better to use SqlCipher, which is available for most platforms, and which will do what you want quite simply.

Comment: @HotLicks Could you expand on why column level encryption is always a very bad idea? SQLCipher looks interesting but not ideal as encrypting the datastore would prevent us from reporting off the database.

Comment: Column-level encryption is a bad idea because the "strength" of a cipher is greatly diminished when you have lots of small ones rather than one big one.  At the very least you'd want to add a random "salt" to each column, at least 4 and perhaps 8 bytes if using a pure random integer, and probably 16 if using a character salt.  (Not clear what you mean by "reporting off the database".  Unlike column encryption you can query any column normally with SqlCipher.)

Comment: @HotLicks The intention is to use AES encryption so I assume the random IV would take care of the salting requirement? By reporting I mean using something like SSRS to create reports from the database. I thought SQLCipher sat between ADO.NET (or equivalent) and the database so all the values in the DB would be encrypted. I must have misunderstood, I'll re-read.

Comment: SqlCipher *is* a database -- an encrypted version of SQLite.  Re salting, if you use a random salt you must include the salt in the encrypted value when you store it.

Comment: Ah ok, I think we're pretty much stuck with SQL Server. But I suppose you would suggest TDE in that case? The only problem with TDE is that it seems to only mitigate the risk of someone stealing your disks. Whereas column level encryption protects against SQL Injection, accidental/intentional data leakage by staff etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on encrypting both the user id and the password, you might want to take a look at [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).  Its an adaptive hashing algorithm, and you can up the encryption complexity whenever you want.  You'll have to use a system-wide salt, which will still make this vulnerable to a dictionary attack.  Your best bet is to randomly generate an account # (with numbers and letters) to use for the client id, that should negate any dictionary attack.  Be sure to make it long enough to be [secure](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/cloudhead/security/how-much-time-is-needed-to-crack-a-password-by-brute-force/).

In general, the user id isn't encrypted because there is no way to [salt](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) the hash of the user id, which makes it vulnerable to attacks.  Before you jump through flaming hoops, I'd make sure that you NEED to encrypt both the client id and password.

Comment: I think my initial example has failed slightly but to continue with your userID and password analogy. Let's say that the UserID did need encrypting and the format was fixed (out of our control and public). We also need to run queries based on that column. Would you think it's better to hash without a salt or encrypt without an IV? Or use a different solution entirely?